# Запрос в SQL (сортировка)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть Таблица `CITIES`, в которой две колонки  `ID` и `City`. `City` - список городов РФ. 
Надо написать SQL запрос, который вернет из таблицы `CITIES` список всех городов РФ, отсортированных в следующем порядке

Первое место - Москва
Второе место - Санкт-Петербург
Все последующие места - остальные города РФ, отсортированные в алфавитном порядке от А до Я

Я Попробовал вот так, но не получается.

```
Select City From Cities where City = 'Moscow' 
UNION 
Select City From Cities where City = 'Sankt-Peterburg'
UNION
Select City From Cities where City !='Moscow' And City != 'Sankt-Peterburg' Order by City
```

Comment: У меня MS-SQL                      .                      .

Comment: Так не ставьте несоответствующие метки :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL:

```
select Id, City
  from Cities
 order by -field(City, 'Санкт-Петербург','Москва'), City
```

Функция `field()` возвращает порядковый номер строки в списке аргументов, если строка не найдена - возвращает 0. В данном случае мы берем ее отрицательной. В итоге Москва даст -2, Спб -1, любые другие города 0. -2 будет первым в порядке сортировки.

Произвольные SQL:

```
select Id, City
  from Cities
 order by case City when 'Москва' then 1
                    when 'Санкт-Петербург' then 2
                    else 3 end,
          City
```

**UPD**: Для MSSQL короткая нотация через функцию поиска позиции строки:

```
select Id, City
  from Cities
 order by -patindex('%$'+City+'$%','$Санкт-Петербург$Москва$'),
          City
```

И универсальный вариант, что бы потом, не меняя запроса, можно было выносить города в начало: В ту-же таблицу или в отдельную добавляем колонку с порядком сортировки. Если отдельной таблицей, то так:

```
create table CitySort(City varchar(100) not null primary key, srt int);
-- Хотя конечно по ID было бы более правильно, чем по названию ...
insert into CitySort values('Москва',1), ('Санкт-Петербург',2);

select Id, City
  from Cities a
  left join CitySort s on s.City=a.City
 order by coalesce(s.srt,99999), City
```

Comment: Про `field()` я знал, а вот трюк с минусом - это круто!

Comment: Спасибо второй вариант сработал. не знал про "case" в сортировке order by.  Первый вариант несработал, потому что у меня MS-SQL, но тоже спасибо. про field()  тоже не знал.  А какие ещё варианты могут быть - просто интересно ? ))

Comment: @Vosxodnik2 Что то в mssql маловато интересных функций, вот только с patindex придумал. В оракле красиво было бы, в нем функция удачная для выбора есть: `decode(City, 'Москва',1,'Санкт-Петербург',2,3)`

Comment: @Mike  Да, получилось.спасибо. Получается это аналогичная функция как field() в My-SQL ? и последний вопрос: где можно почитать про эти функции ?  вообще какой учебник для начинающего SQL разработчика посоветуйте ?).  я решаю задачки на sql-ex.ru.  Но аринтируясь в основном этим на работу устроиться не получиться

Comment: @Vosxodnik2 Учебников ни разу в руках не держал и на ms sql не работал. просто в гугле нахожу скажем "функции mssql". и смотрю что умеют. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms181984(v=sql.120).aspx    А patindex() ищет позицию в строке, так что вернет не 1,2,3 а смещение, но нам то в данном случае без разницы, главное что значения больше-меньше

Comment: @Mike Ok, Спасибо !

Comment: Пардон, я не нарочно). плохо знаю правила тут. я хотел рейтинг ответа поднять, не получилось - у меня рейтинг низкий

Comment: @cyadvert забавно, да, но `DESC` всё ж идиоматичнее :)